# How to compute the expectation of an element within a vector?

Tags: probability

Say we have $\Theta = (\Theta_1, \ldots, \Theta_n)$ and $p_{\Theta}(\theta)$, how do we compute $\mathbb{E}[\Theta_j]$? Do we need to do an integral over all $\Theta_i$? If so, I don't see why. In [this video](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+6.041x_4+1T2017/courseware/Unit_7_Bayesian_inference/Lec__16_Least_mean_squares__LMS__estimation/?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMITx%2B6.041x_4%2B1T2017%2Btype%40sequential%2Bblock%40Lec__16_Least_mean_squares__LMS__estimation), I don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to see this in two dimensions. Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and support $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, by definition,

$$ E[X] = \iint_{A}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy\;\;\; \& \;\;\; E[Y] = \iint_{A}yf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

Can you try to extend this to some vector $(\Theta_1,...,\Theta_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$? It would involve an $n$-dimensional integral.

Comment: thank you, this cleared it up for me!